# Kibana couldnt estabilish connection to Elasticsearch inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, centos, kibana

I'm trying to run Elastic,Kibana inside docker-compose.

When I bring up the containers using `docker-compose up`, Elasticsearch loads up fine. After it loads, the Kibana containers start up. But once they load, they are not able to see or connect the Elasticsearch container, producing these messages:

Kibana docker Log:

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-22T19:57:27Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":6,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-22T19:57:30Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":6,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch01:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2020-01-22T19:57:30Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","data"],"pid":6,"message":"No living connections"}
```

Am not able to see the elasticsearch host from the Kibana container

`curl -X GET http://elasticsearch01:9200`

throws below quoted error

> curl: (7) Failed connect to elasticsearch01:9200; No route to host

Deeply digged and out this is happening only in *CentOS8* .
Also in same *CENTOS8* am able to up and use standalone elasticsearch and kibana instance via `systemctl service`.

Am i missing something here ?
Can anyone help?

docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  docker-elk:
    driver: bridge

services:
  elasticsearch01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1
    container_name: elasticsearch01
    secrets:
      - source: elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    restart: always
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - elasticdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200"
    expose: 
      - "9200"
      - "9300"
    networks:
      - docker-elk

  kibana:  
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.5.1
    container_name: kibana
    depends_on: ['elasticsearch01']
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME=kibanaServer
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - source: kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
    restart: always
    networks:
      - docker-elk
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports: ['5601:5601']
    links:
      - elasticsearch01
volumes:
  elasticdata:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local

secrets:
  elasticsearch.yml:
    file: ./ELK_Config/elastic/elasticsearch.yml
  kibana.yml:
    file: ./ELK_Config/kibana/kibana.yml
```

**System/Docker Info**
OS: CentOS 8
ELK versions 7.4.0
Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a
Docker-compose:docker-compose version 1.25.0, build 0a186604

Comment: Give us your docker compose file please : )

Comment: hi @IanGabes , Have edited and added `docker-compose.yml` file to question for your reference .

Comment: Hey, I read this article about CentOS 8 as the host OS. It might be the case that the built in firewall is blocking DNS resolution for the docker network. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-docker-in-rhel-8 It might be a good idea to try disabling the firewall, and then trying again. `sudo systemctl disable firewalld`

Comment: @IanGabes yah i had suspect on the `CentOS 8` cause the same working in other linux os as docker host os . 

May be i'll try doing the same , but have query whether is it advisable to disable firewall in production environment ?

Comment: @IanGabes Hi , with answer/spark you gave i was able to find solutions instead of fully disabling the `firewalld`, able to find a go-round by bypassing the docker DNS in firewall using the step shown in [here](https://serverfault.com/a/994704/556974) 

Post doing the steps, kibana able to connect with Elastic inside docker ..   


Thanks :)